# Angular performance massively downgraded using 1.2 or even 1.3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

So I've been using an unstable version of Angular for the past 2 years... and it's worked great.  I've been on 1.1.5 without issue.  It's never caused me trouble, at least that I'm aware of, so why upgrade?  Well, I decided it was time yesterday and decided to upgrade to 1.3.10 to see if some bugs that were popping up were related, as well as taking advantage of more present features such as native one way binding.

Upon upgrading to 1.3.10, the performance of my app went from from zippy fast, to almost unusable.  We have one page that functions similarly to Google, where it returns about 50 results on the front page.  Those results are made up of objects with about 14 string properties, and maybe an array or two of anywhere from 1-10 elements.  Maybe I'm wrong, but that doesn't seem like a lot of data to crunch through.  When using 1.1.5, the results appear in roughly 1-2 seconds max.  When upgrading to 1.3.10, it takes **upwards of 12 seconds** to render the elements while hard locking the page.

On another page, we have a dashboard type screen where you can view 3 different chart types, and do some filtering and some statistical operations on the data.  It hits one of our services, returns back some results for the two controls and then poulates the controls with roughly 100-200 elements where an ng-repeat would have to iterate over objects that really consist of 3 or 4 properties each.  On 1.1.5, the page takes about a couple seconds to gather all the data from the associated service, and then it's ready to go.  On 1.3.10, it locks for a while, is completely unresponsive, and then the entire page turns white and I can't close the tab without hard closing it.

I read a bit on on the Angular Core issue list, and saw that others were seeing pretty noticeable downgrades in performance moving from 1.2 -> 1.3, so I tried switching to 1.2.8.  Performance difference was negligible.

It seems hard to believe that upgrading from a 2 year old, unstable version of a framework to the most modern release would cause these issues.  I'm really not sure what to do here, as I am uncomfortable continuing to run on such an old, unstable release, but it works like a charm, whereas the latest code brings the app to its knees.  I'm sure there's some design changes I should be making, as when I started this, Angular was in its infancy and I cut my teeth on it with this app.  But I can't imagine what I'd need to change, or what was done to cause this kind of decrease.

I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions on what could be causing this, or what I can do to rectify this issue.

Comment: Can you show some context? Also, tools such a Batarang may help. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en

Comment: I think because you don't upgrade everything. There are lots of changes from 1.15 to 1.3.1. It is not a quick upgrade when you are out of date so long. I would suggest you go thru the change log and doc and then back to read your code. It is not a simple task. For the record, I don't feel any performance issue downgrade from 1.1x to 1.2 x

Answer (score -1):

First things first: you just learned why you should not update any parts unless you absolutely NEED something from the update. I hope you are using version control or can otherwise easily revert the change. in case you still want to use Angular 1.3, make a separate branch for this in your version control.

Now, there are 2 options here:

1. You don't upgrade Angular and keep using 1.1.5. This is the easy way. It does mean you miss out on everything added after that version, but your software will remain stable. Please note that "unstable version" for Angular means that they might change features or the API between minor versions. It does NOT mean that, if you remain on the same version, your software will break easily.
2. You read up on ALL the changes made in Angular between 1.1.5 and the version you want to use. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md has the entire changelog written out. Based on that, check which changes you need to make in order to update. It is highly possible that something that you're currently using Angular for has changed in functionality and will require a fix.

I apologise for not being able to give you more specific information, but unless you share some specific code that gives issues, we can't help you more accurately. The only advice I can give you is that a likely culprit is an expensive method being called more often now.

Comment: @maxisam Unfortunately, it's not that simple. Regular upgrades can be useful, but it shouldn't be the automatic behavior. If something isn't broken, don't fix it. Don't just update something because there's a newer version, because as the OP noticed, newer versions mean changes that can affect your software performance and correctness. Especially if it's something that needs to run on the client computer, since you don't have control over the specs of that machine. That is something that as far as I know most software developers and system administrators agree on.

Comment: "If something isn't broken, don't fix it." You do realize you are in web app business right ? Everything keeps changing. Eventually you need to update things. Why do you wait until it becomes a painful thing ? No one is saying catching every single update. But having a regular update schedule is not like very hard.

Comment: Besides, it is not like refactoring a bad but working code. Upgrading does serve benefit in the long run if the application has potential growth in the future.